# otool error : is not an object file

Tags: macos, assembly, otool

I have two files on Mac OS. One Mach-O executable i386 and one data (same exec icon in my Finder).

When I execute otool -tV command on the first I have my assembler code printed. But when I write it for my second file I have this message : myFile: is not an object file.

Have an idea how to convert or directly read data files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error from `otool` is because the data file is not a [Mach-O object file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O), which has a pre-defined format used to store code, data, symbols etc.

It's not possible (or nearly impossible) to just convert a data file into an Object file.